# EncryptByPassPhrase rounding off numbers greater than 6 digits

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012

EncryptByPassPhrase and Decryptbypassphrase in SQL Server rounds off the values as shown in the image. How can we fix this? We are using SQL server 2012

```
DECLARE @EncryptedValue varbinary(8000); 
DECLARE @MyFloat float;

SET     @MyFloat = 1204787;  

SELECT  @EncryptedValue = EncryptByPassPhrase('x12#', CAST(@MyFloat AS varchar(8000)));

SELECT  @MyFloat as 'before', @EncryptedValue,   
        CAST(CAST(decryptbypassphrase('x12#', @EncryptedValue) as varchar(8000)) as float)  as 'after';
```

[image]

Comment: Take out all of the encryption stuff. It's irrelevant. Just run `SELECT  CAST(@MyFloat AS varchar(8000));` and examine the output.

Comment: The documentation on [float and real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) indicates that you should prefer `STR` over `CAST`.

Comment: Thanks, Damien. STR did the trick, please post your comment as an answer and I will set it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Damien mentioned in the comments this is due to SQL truncating float values when using 'CAST'. we need to use STR instead. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)